# SQL Server 2008 Time column messing up GridView DataFormatString

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, gridview, timespan

I've got a **nullable** column in **SQL Server 2008** that I use to store a **time**.  When I use **LINQ to SQL** and pull data back it comes back as **TimeSpan?**.  When I bind that to a GridView and try to format it using **DataFormatString="{0:t}"** it still shows the seconds.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `TimeSpan` doesn't implement [IFormatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.aspx). So you can't directly format TimeSpans.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you also disable Html encoding for your format to work.

```
HtmlEncode="false"
```

Comment: Good suggestion.  It looks like this has something to do with how .NET uses TimeSpans for Times instead of DateTimes.